# How can I store data frames produced in a loop in a list, to be able to call them by name later?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, storing-data

In a loop, I am applying a function to a column of a data frame. I am storing this result in another data frame which I create in the loop. I would like to store these created  data frames in a list, to be able to call upon them later to be able to perform functions on them. (ex. merge(list[1], list[2])) This is failing terribly.

I have tried various different functions like get, mget, but it seems that there are some fundamental errors I am committing.

```
library(qdap)

for (l in 1:9)
  {
     temp1 <- freq_terms(df[[paste0("col_0", l, sep="")]]) #i perform function freq_terms over the columns col_01, col_02..., col_09 of df

      assign(paste0("freq",l,sep =""),temp1)
#then I store this result in freq1, freq2, freq3....freq9

            dfstm[l] = list ((paste0("freq",l,sep ="")))

 #then I would like to store the resulting data frame from assign into a list, though I am aware here I am only storing characters...
  }
```

I would like to do the following;

```
merge(dfstm[1], dfstm[2])
```

to be able to get a merged list of "WORD" and "FREQ". However, the only result I get is "freq1 freq2" where merge merges the string rather than the object.

How can I resolve this? Help would be most appreciated!

Here is some sample data from the 'freq' matrices. There are 'l' of them produced. Then these names are stored in the list.

```
dput(head(freq1,5))
structure(list(WORD = c("manufacturing", "care", "consumer", 
"health", "goods"), FREQ = c(16, 10, 10, 10, 9)), row.names = c(24L, 
8L, 12L, 22L, 20L), class = c("freq_terms", "all_words", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to test without  a sample of your data sets. Please provide some dummy data with `dput(head(df,n))` or some small data sets that represent your data.

Comment: @NelsonGon , I edited the question to include some data. Hope it's helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess on what you're trying to achieve, but why don't use simply use lapply?

```
res <- lapply(1:9, function(i){
         temp <- freq_terms(df[[paste0("col_0", i, sep="")]])
         temp}
)
```

Then you get a list with elements that you can individually access and merge.

Comment: thanks for the tip, however, there seems to be a syntax error and I can't try your solution. Error is 'Unmatched opening Bracket'. I am unfamiliar with the apply family and thus can't quite figure out where to put it...